# IntelliJ Idea on MacOS: Move toolbar away from main menu

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I'm usually working with IntelliJ IDEA on MacOS in fullscreen mode. When I try to access something in the toolbar, I often overshoot the target a little, and the main menu bar opens instead, hiding the toolbar. So I have to move the mouse a little lower, wait and move carefully into the toolbar again. This is quite annoying. Are there any tips to avoid this? Is it possible to move the toolbar, say, to the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment, but there are 2 open requests you can vote for:

- [IDEA-119950](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119950) A setting in the settings area to stop 'show on hover' menu in fullscreen
- [IDEA-117034](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117034) Fullscreen menu bar is too eager to show